# android scedule task in to run some code once a day

Tags: java, android

I am making a small android APP and I want to have some code that runs once a day at 6AM. When the app is not running to update some parameters and send a notification to the user telling them to enter the app. Can someone help me by telling me the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so with alarm manager, pending intent and a broadcast receiver.  This code will wake up the device every two hours:

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    //set the alarms to start in the time period
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,60000);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent getSqlUpdatesTimer = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 7200000, getSqlUpdatesTimer);
```

And your broadcast receiver:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent != null) {

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
            wl.acquire();

            //Some code to do your task

            wl.release();
    }

}
}
```

You also need to have the wakelock permission set in your Manifest.

Comment: Does this work even when the device has been rebooted and the user hasn't explicitly opened the app up again ?